# How does one get the x- and y-ranges of a series in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

How does one get the x- and y-ranges of a series in VBA?

The VBA code should then look something like this:

```
Sub Getxyrng(ch as chart)
Dim ser As series
Dim xrng As Range
Dim yrng As Range

Set ser = ch.SeriesCollection(1) ' the series with a x- and y-range already referenced

Set xrng = ser.xvalues 'this doesn't work
Set yrng = ser.Values  'what would the code need to look like in order to return a range?

End Sub
```

**So the question is which property of the series-type is the x-/y-range that contain the source data of ther series.** If you change the range manually it looks like this:

[image]

So manually this is accessible like this: left click>select data>edit

Which means that there must be a property that saves these range references.

Comment: Whenever you can do something manually in Excel and you are wondering how it is translated to VBA, the best possible answer is - record a "macro" and see for yourself.

Comment: Parse the  `.formula` property?

Comment: @JohnColeman That looks doable. Thanks =D I'll answer the question myself if I got it done.

Comment: @LucasRaphaelPianegonda Looks doable but seems ugly. I've never liked how Excel VBA handles charts. Seems like this problem deserves a clear answer (assuming it isn't a duplicate), so I will upvote if you do so.

Comment: So you want an object that contains the reference to the range that is used for the specific series in the graph?

Comment: @Luuklag I need the range were the sourcedata is. The question is how to get it. The first approach is to parse `.formula` in order to extract the x-and y-range references and than use `Range(ref)` to get the ranges. Super ugly but will most probably work.

Comment: I think you might be after this:  http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?30968-Finding-data-range-reference-for-a-series-in-chart-using-vba

Comment: @Luuklag That is only a partial solution, since you assume there that the title of your series has no comma in it. So It doesn't always work. I would have parsed out the last apostrophe and then use the commas as separators. That should then always work.

Comment: @LucasRaphaelPianegonda didn't really look into every detail of it. But I knew I'd seen something like this before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would something along these lines work for you?

```
Sub GetSourceCellsAddress()

Dim MyArr() As String
Dim xrng As Range, yrng As Range

MyArr() = Split(ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Formula, ",")
Set yrng = Range(MyArr(UBound(MyArr) - 1))
Set xrng = Range(MyArr(UBound(MyArr) - 2))

End Sub
```

**Input:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: `.formula` is always structured like this `=SERIES("SeriesName",xRef,yRef,1)` but if 'SeriesName' contains a comma. The function doesn't work. So what you first need to do, is to remove the `SeriesName`.

Comment: @LucasRaphaelPianegonda, I get what you mean but hence why I used ubound -1 and -2 of array. Whether there are 1 or a 100 comma's in the title, it will always return the correct y and x ranges.

Comment: Now I get it. Pretty elegant like this.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I admit it. I am not very proud of the solution but it does the job. As already pointed out in the comments of the question one way of solving this is to parse the `.formula` property. One point to pay attention to is that the series title can contain a comma, therefore the solution first filters to the last appostrophe and then uses commas as delimiters.

```
Private Function GetSerRng(ser As series, Xval As Boolean) As Range
Dim f As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim parts As New Collection
f = ser.Formula

' filter "
For i = 1 To 2
    f = Right(f, Len(f) - InStr(1, f, """"))
Next i

' split by ,
While InStr(f, ",") <> 0
    parts.Add Replace(Left(f, InStr(2, f, ",")), ",", vbNullString)
    f = Right(f, Len(f) - InStr(2, f, ","))
Wend

' set Range
If Xval Then
Set GetSerRng = Range(parts(1))
Else
Set GetSerRng = Range(parts(2))
End If
End Function
```

It is not the most elegant solution but it works.